# Can you have a Facebook entry in both English and Arabic with proper punctuation?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook page with posts both in English and in Arabic. We give preference to the Arabic language because we are in the Middle East. The problem is in the English portion where the punctuation is all wrong, since Arabic is from right to left and in English the post is left to right.

What happens is, in the English post, the punctuation often goes to the next line. For example a question mark is at the beginning of a line and not connected with the thought.

Is there a way to fix this without creating separate posts?